# Is there a way to get class names of all view controllers of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

Finding the view controllers presented at run-time by traversing view controller hierarchy is not the thing I am asking here, I know it is trivial. I simply want to get class names of all view controllers that "might" be presented/pushed for the current build. I think this can be achieved by recursively traversing files in project folder hierarchy. But getting the class name cannot pave a way for us to check whether that class is an `UIViewController` subclass. Maybe it is possible in a way. If you know an approach to realize this task, please share with me.

Comment: Can you let me know what you're trying to do with this? Does this need to happen at runtime? Are you trying to build a diagram for documentation?

Comment: I am trying to take screenshot of all possible screens automatically and match these images with view controllers. It does not matter if it happens at run time or compile time as much as I get what I want. :)

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, I'm not sure of how you'd accomplish this, however you could dig up the view controllers with a Regex string in the "Find Navigator":

`^class.*: UIViewController$`

[image]

Comment: Thanks but what about this case; "class X: Y { }", "class Y: UIViewController { }"? How can I fetch X which is an UIViewController sub-subclass? Also, even I find out all the classes, still it is hard to get relevant view controller objects at this point.

Comment: Dot star captures a string of anything, so that regex is looking for a line that starts with class + whatever (*.) + : UIViewController